# /Applications/Clozure CL.app/Contents/Resources/ccl/dx86cl64.image: cannot execute binary file

Tags: emacs, common-lisp, slime

**Setup:**

MacOS 10.12.4

Clozure CL Version 1.11.1 (16714)

Emacs Version 25.1 (9.0)

**Problem:**

Clozure CL app starts, REPL runs.

Emacs inferior-list function terminates with:

```
(progn (load "/Users/Szabolcs/.emacs.d/elpa/slime-20170319.1601/swank-loader.lisp" :verbose t) (funcall (read-from-string "swank-loader:init")) (funcall (read-from-string "swank:start-server") "/var/folders/v7/st79grks643g7c3q_dhhb88r0000gn/T/slime.49146"))

/usr/local/bin/ccl64: line 81: /Applications/Clozure CL.app/Contents/Resources/ccl/dx86cl64.image: cannot execute binary file
/usr/local/bin/ccl64: line 81: /Applications/Clozure CL.app/Contents/Resources/ccl/dx86cl64.image: Undefined error: 0

Process inferior-lisp exited abnormally with code 1
```

init.el

```
(require 'slime)
(setq inferior-lisp-program "/usr/local/bin/ccl64 -K utf-8")
(require 'slime)
(setq slime-net-coding-system 'utf-8-unix)
(slime-setup '(slime-fancy))
;; (prefer-coding-system 'utf-8)
;; (set-terminal-coding-system 'utf-8)
(slime)

(add-hook 'slime-mode-hook #'paredit-mode)
```

- I tried to modify owner and group, if maybe that causes it not to run. But didn't work out.

Answer (score 1):

From the [home-site](http://ccl.clozure.com/install.html) of clozure CL. They recomment to set the inferior-lisp-program to lx86cl64 binary it should be

(setq inferior-lisp-program "/path/to/ccl/lx86cl64")

But Nowadays I use roswell for installing and using Lisp I use [roswell](https://github.com/roswell/roswell/wiki/1.-Installation) (is like rvm for lisp), it has a complet an [easy setup](https://github.com/roswell/roswell/wiki/1.1-Initial-Recommended-Setup), and then you can use it with the majority of lisp distributions

Comment: `dx86cl, dx86cl64 OS X (Darwin) x86, x86-64 darwinx8632. darwinx8664` Actually, for all systems there is an appropriate image. The strange thing is, that the app's default listener works. But when I try to start the image file from command-line or call from emacs (which is ultimately the same as calling it from the terminal), it won't execute.

Comment: I will try this roswell you've recommended. Thanks for the recommendation! Should I remove the Clozure CL instance installed from the AppStore before starting working with roswell?

Comment: Rebuilding also complains: `? (ccl:rebuild-ccl :full t)
Rebuilding Clozure Common Lisp using Version 1.11-store-r16714  (DarwinX8664)
> Error: Permission denied : #P"/Applications/Clozure CL.app/Contents/Resources/ccl/tools/asdf.dx64fsl"
> While executing: REBUILD-CCL, in process Listener(4).
> Type cmd-. to abort, cmd-\ for a list of available restarts.
> Type :? for other options.`

Comment: I suppose that is better to unintall all lisps, and then proceed with roswell from zero, really I do not have all that problems with roswell, please forget all about other before installations

Comment: I did delete all lisps. (Except Clojure, which doesn't belong to this ecosystem.) Still I'm having issues.